# Trying to install R 4.0.1, but having an issue with Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, data-science, package-management

I tried to upgrade the last version of R in my ubuntu server, following other blogs I uninstall R from my server and I tried to install doing these steps:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/'

sudo apt update
```

I followed these steps from here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04

When I tried to run the last command:   `sudo apt-get install r-base`

I got this error:

```
sudo apt install r-base

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.2-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.2-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
```

`apt-cache policy r-base` yield:

```
-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.2-1.1804.0
  Version table:
     4.0.2-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
     3.4.4-1xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.3-1xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.2-2xenial2 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.2-1xenial1 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.1-2xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.1-1xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.4.0-1xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.3-1xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.2-1xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.1-1xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.0-2xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.3.0-1xenial0 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
     3.2.5-1xenial 500
        500 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Packages
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quoted output is partial and we cannot see what is *really* behind it.

My *suspicion* is that some other package the binary depends on is too old. *In general* the `apt install` command assumes a *current* system.  So maybe try

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install r-base
```

and update your question with any "odd" errors you are seeing. I maintain the underlying Debian package `r-base`, and run these same Ubuntu binaries on several machines too without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue...what kind of processor are you on? This happened to me because I was installing on an arm64 machine, and the main cran repo does not have packages for that architecture. I removed the reference to the cran repository in /etc/apt/sources.list (just using a text editor) and installed from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports. This worked fine, but I have an older version of R than what's available on the cran repo. I'll either have to find a different source for the packages, or compile locally, or live with R 3.4.4.

Comment: Look at the logs which show `amd64`. So a different issue.

Comment: I have arm64 running on Debian 10 Buster (Lenovo Chromebook with Linux). I am having the same problem. Can you be more explicit about how you installed R?